# WCF using computer name instead of domain name when viewing MyService.svc?wsdl

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis, ssl, configuration

My WCF serice seems to be using the computer-name instead of the domain name. When I view the `MyService.svc?wsdl` link it is showing my computer name.

Where do I add my domain name in the web.config? Endpoint address, baseaddress or identity?

Note: I am using SSL so it has to be `https://www.example.com/myservice.svc`

Comment: See if this [post](http://jstawski.com/archive/2008/05/01/wcf-wsdl-location-address-with-https.aspx) can help.

Comment: what a hack.  Is this a known bug because I can't see how shared hosters handle this!

Answer (score 27):

WCF 4.0 has solved this issue in some instances with a new config option that use Request Headers:

```
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="AutoVaultUploadBehavior">
                <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
                    <defaultPorts>
                        <add scheme="https" port="443" />
                    </defaultPorts>
                </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
```

Comment: and for http? how to do it?

Answer (score 9):

For IIS7 you don't add it to web.config, but to the IIS configuration file.

First off edit the bindings for your web site so the HTTP protocol specifies a host name if you haven't already - this will ensure it gets the correct name under HTTP.

Navigate to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config and open applicationHost.config

Look for the sites section. You will see something like the following

```
<sites>
  <site name="Default Web Site" id="1">
    <application path="/">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:puck" />
      <binding protocol="net.tcp" bindingInformation="808:*" />
      <binding protocol="net.pipe" bindingInformation="*" />
      <binding protocol="net.msmq" bindingInformation="localhost" />
      <binding protocol="msmq.formatname" bindingInformation="localhost" />
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:puck.idunno.org" />
      <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:localhost" />
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:" />
    </bindings>
  </site>
  ....
</sites>
```

You can see that the bindings for the http protocol specify a host header, but https doesn't. When you're web browsing you can't use host headers over HTTPS, but WCF still uses it when generating the WSDL - if it can't find one it will fall back to the machine name.

So all you need to do is edit the HTTPS binding like so

```
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:puck" />
```

appending the correct FQDN to the end of the binding information. Reset IIS and WCF should get it right now.

The IIS6 solution has already been posted by darin

Comment: This works, but I run into a problem only the exact domain name I specify will work. For example if I do:
    *:443:domain.com
Then only domain.com/Service.svc will work, if I do:
    *:443:www.domain.com
Then only www.domain.com/Service.svc will work, but not both. How can I get both? (With https prefix)

Answer (score 8):

As stated in this link [WCF is using the computer name instead of the IP address and cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863464/wcf-is-using-the-computer-name-instead-of-the-ip-address-and-cannot-be-resolved)

It solved my problem, maybe because i have multiple web sites in the same host, and is very simple.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 4):

To fix this problem Configure the httpGetEnabled attribute and httpsGetEnabled attribute in web.config file

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
```

Comment: Simple, easy, exactly what is needed.  Don't know why everyone else is suggesting all these other complicated solutions.  This does exactly what the OP wants.

Answer (score 3):

We're using [WCFExtras](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/) to change the name of the host.

WCFExtras is a small open source library that will allow you to write the following to change the host name:

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="xxx">
      <wsdlExtensions location="http://some-hostname-visible-from-outside/path-to-a-service/service.svc" singleFile="True" />
    </behavior>
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

just adding 
  `<useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress></useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>`  to the  solved my issue.
It seems that WCF 4.0 takes care of the Headers by adding this 
I was using SSL for accessing the WCF Service.

Answer (score 1):

I have added solutions here, http://knowledgebaseworld.blogspot.com/2010/06/domain-name-replaced-with-machine-name.html. it should work for you all as its working fine with me on local, staging and production without doing binding on iis

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions were helpful to me. I was able to solve this with a very simple custom Service Factory.

[Installing a WCF Service on a Shared Hosting Site, Revisited](http://www.itscodingtime.com/post/Installing-a-WCF-Service-on-a-Shared-Hosting-Site-Revisited.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [setting the host header in IIS](http://gavinmckay.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/howto-fix-wcf-host-name-on-iis/)?

Answer (score 1):

Although its an old posting, here is an answer.
Under Service Behaviour --> ServiceMetaData add service url.

Please note if you do not add myService, it will throw another error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this very issue with my production server. I have found various articles on the multiple host headers with IIS and WCF issue, but if you are using SSL, you cannot add a host header to the website identities within the IIS UI, you can only add them to normal HTTP identities:

[image]

However you can add SSL host headers via a command prompt script, and this solved the issue for me:

```
cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set /w3svc/<site identifier>/SecureBindings ":443:<host header>"
```

For more information on this see this link: http://blumenthalit.net/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=14

Answer (score 0):

This post solved it for me. I needed to associate my domain name with my IP address and website in IIS.

http://www.codemeit.com/wcf/wcf-wsdl-xsdimport-schemalocations-link-to-local-machine-name-not-domain-name-while-hosted-in-iis.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kanasz Robert.
Steps that solved my problem - 
1.Produce the wsdl in the browser and save to file (by hitting .svc?wsdl from browser) save as .wsdl

2. Produce the xsd files by hitting url from wsdl (xsd=xsd0, etc), and save to file from browser, save as .wsdl
3. replace all machine name references from wsdl with domain name (or ip address) and change xsd references and save AND replace all machine name references from xsd files with domain name (or ip address)
   make sure to name xsd file with .xsd extension (ie, name0.xsd, name1.xsd, name2.xsd)
4. copy wsdl and xsd file(s) to virtual directory
   add to your web.config following lines:

```html
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" externalMetadataLocation="http://IPorDomainName/MyServices/FileTransferService.wsdl"  />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```