# How to set the base path in IIS 7 hosting a WCF application?

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, iis-7

I've been fighting my way through the process of migrating a (previously self-hosted) WCF application to IIS7 (I've never used IIS before and I realise that this is a very simplistic question but I failed to google/SO the answer so far).

My service is hosted at `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/SampleWebsite/Service.svc` but when I access it with `?wsdl` all the references that should read `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/` are actually set to the window machine's local network name (i.e. `http://localpc3/`).

I've tried using the WCF tool to add the external IP address to the base address section under the service I'm configuring as well as a number of settings inside IIS manager but I can't seem to track down the correct place.

Where do I set this?  IIS manager, web.config, somewhere else?

---

> May be a duplicate:
>   [WCF not using my domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470111/wcf-not-using-my-domain-name-but-rather-my-computer-name-when-viewing-myservice)

---

Answer:

Change it in the metabase:

```
cscript.exe %systemdrive%\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs 
      set W3SVC/your_website_identifier_here/ServerBindings ":80:myserver.example.com"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to modify the IIS Metabase.
See here:

http://gavinmckay.wordpress.com/2009/03/24/howto-fix-wcf-host-name-on-iis/

Comment: Would appreciate if you could summarize the answer in the post.