# WCF svcutil Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from localhost

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-6, metadata, svcutil.exe

I've been looking around the questions here to see if anything similar was addressed already.
I've yet to find a solution so hopefully someone can help out and point me in the right direction.

I have a service and I can successfully navigate to the svc page on my localhost.

https://localhost/WebSite/UploadService/UploadService.svc

This works as expected as does viewing the wsdl by appending ?wsdl to the url.

However I can't generate the client proxy using svcutil.

> svcutil.exe
>   https://localhost/Website/UploadService/UploadService.svc?wsdl

When I run this command I get the usual

> Attempting to download metadata from
>   'https://localhost/Website/UploadService/UploadService.svc'
>   using WS-Metadata Exc hange or DISCO.
>   Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata
>   Tool [Microsoft (R) Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation, Version
>   3.0.4506.2152] Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   https://localhost/Website/UploadService/UploadService.svc
>
> WS-Metadata Exchange Error
>       URI: https://localhost/Website/UploadService/UploadService.svc
>
> ```
> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
> ```
>
> 'https://localhost/Website/UploadService/UploadService.svc'
>   .
>       Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure
>   channel with authority 'localhost'.
>       The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
>   relationship for the SSL/TLS secure
>   channel.
>       The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
>
> HTTP GET Error
>       URI: https://localhost/Website/UploadService/UploadService.svc
>       There was an error downloading 'https://localhost/Website/UploadService/UploadService.svc'.
>       The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
>   relationship for the SSL/TLS secure
>   channel.
>       The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

I went over [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403806/how-to-set-the-base-path-in-iis-7-hosting-a-wcf-application/2416539#2416539) and tried what it outlines. The server name is consistent after following those suggestions but I'm still unable to generate the client proxy files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i see what's been happening now
it was all about the certificates
the certificate you use in IIS plays an important role here
if you expect your service to be at localhost, your test certificate that you assign in IIS must be issued to localhost.