# https cloud service redirecting to unkown Basic HTTP bind address

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, azure

I have recently upgraded my Azure hosted WCF web service to support SSL by adding the certificate to the domain, setting up the CNAME record and configuring the web service config files httpsGetEnabled="true".

The http web service is online and hosted here : http://api.verveconsortium.eu/VerveService.svc

The HTTPS web service is available by adding the HTTPS protocol to the link here: https://api.verveconsortium.eu/VerveService.svc

The problem I am having is that when I access the HTTP service the executable URL changes to:

```
https://rd00155d52225f/VerveService.svc?wsdl
```

I originally thought this problem was due to the empty address field in the basicHttpBinding tag. I have tried changing the address and setting the default address to the api.verveconsortium but it still defaults back to the URL which I have no idea where its coming from. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: looks like wcf is using instance name in binding, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863464/wcf-is-using-the-computer-name-instead-of-the-ip-address-and-cannot-be-resolved or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470111/wcf-not-using-my-domain-name-but-rather-my-computer-name-when-viewing-myservice

Comment: tried a couple of these and it didn't do the trick. When I change httpGetEnabled to true it changes the problem around to work on http and fail on https. I think I need to setup separate endpoints and binds for each one but I don't understand where that unkown URL is coming from to manually override it.

Comment: unknown url comes from instance name. how do you host your wcf in azure - in VM, azure websites, web role?

Comment: have you tried both httpGetEnabled and httpsGetEnabled to be true in your config